# How cache management grid renders in Magento?

Tags: magento2, magento-cache-management

I was thinking to make an invalid cache selected on page load for an easy refresh.
But when I saw the code, I didn't find any UI component for listing these caches.
Can anyone describe how Magento listing these caches in the grid?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Cache managment grid define in Magento_Backend Module.**

> **Layout file path :-**
>
> ```
> vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_cache_block.xml
> ```